# Puzzled over Float vs Double benchmark

Tags: c#, .net, windows, floating-point, benchmarking

After searching SO for performance differences between floats and doubles in .NET, I put together a simple benchmark to test 2 methods, each with floats and doubles, debug and release.  After running the benchmark a few times, I became puzzled by the timing results between float and double from the Func2Double and Func2Float methods in the x64-release build.  Func2Double behaved (slow benchmark times) like it was a debug build.  The other methods (Func1Double, Func1Float, Func2Float) all produced much faster benchmark times (as expected) than their debug counterparts.  I compared the IL for the float and double versions of the x64-release build but did not find any notable differences that would explain the results I was getting.

Can anyone explain what is going on with the benchmark results for Func2Double in BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x64-release.exe?

Here is the source code I tested:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BenchmarkFloatVsDouble
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OSDescription: {0}", RuntimeInformation.OSDescription);
            Console.WriteLine("OSArchitecture: {0}", RuntimeInformation.OSArchitecture);
            Console.WriteLine("ProcessArchitecture: {0}", RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture);
            Console.WriteLine("FrameworkDescription: {0}", RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription);

            Console.WriteLine();

            var ev = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
            Console.WriteLine("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432: {0}", ev["PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"]);
            Console.WriteLine("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: {0}", ev["PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE"]);
            Console.WriteLine("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: {0}", ev["PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER"]);
            Console.WriteLine("NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: {0}", ev["NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS"]);

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Is64BitProcess: {0}", Environment.Is64BitProcess);
            Console.WriteLine("Is64BitOperatingSystem: {0}", Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem);

            Console.WriteLine();

            using (var p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            {
                p.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime;
            }

            var template = "{0,15}, {1,15}, {2,15}, {3,15}";

            Console.WriteLine(
             template,
             "Func1Double",
             "Func1Float",
             "Func2Double",
             "Func2Float");

            var count = 100 * 1000 * 1000;
            var v1 = 1.23456789D;
            var v2 = 1.23456789F;

            for (var ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)
            {
                var t1 = Environment.TickCount;
                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) Func1Double(v1);
                var d1 = Environment.TickCount - t1;

                var t2 = Environment.TickCount;
                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) Func1Float(v2);
                var d2 = Environment.TickCount - t2;

                var t3 = Environment.TickCount;
                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) Func2Double(v1);
                var d3 = Environment.TickCount - t3;

                var t4 = Environment.TickCount;
                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) Func2Float(v2);
                var d4 = Environment.TickCount - t4;

                Console.WriteLine(template, d1, d2, d3, d4);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static double Func1Double(double x)
        {
            return Math.Exp(-x * x);
        }

        public static float Func1Float(float x)
        {
            return (float)Math.Exp(-x * x);
        }

        public static double Func2Double(double x)
        {
            return 1d - (1d / (1d + (x * x)));
        }

        public static float Func2Float(float x)
        {
            return 1f - (1f / (1f + (x * x)));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I created the executables.  I know I could have done a batch build of the 4 variations (x86/x64 x debug/release) in VS, but I wanted to be able to show all the steps here.  I did the same tests with the csc.exe that comes with .NET 4 but got the same results.

```
D:\files\dev\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble>csc /platform:x64 /optimize- /debug+ /debug:full /define:DEBUG;TRACE /out:BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x64-debug.exe Program.cs

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.2.0-beta4-19380-04 (5e176ad8)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


D:\files\dev\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble>csc /platform:x64 /optimize+ /debug- /debug:pdbonly /define:TRACE /out:BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x64-release.exe Program.cs

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.2.0-beta4-19380-04 (5e176ad8)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


D:\files\dev\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble>csc /platform:x86 /optimize- /debug+ /debug:full /define:DEBUG;TRACE /out:BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x86-debug.exe Program.cs

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.2.0-beta4-19380-04 (5e176ad8)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


D:\files\dev\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble>csc /platform:x86 /optimize+ /debug- /debug:pdbonly /define:TRACE /out:BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x86-release.exe Program.cs

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.2.0-beta4-19380-04 (5e176ad8)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Here are the results of running the 4 different builds.

```
D:\files\dev\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble>BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x64-release.exe

OSDescription: Microsoft Windows 10.0.16299
OSArchitecture: X64
ProcessArchitecture: X64
FrameworkDescription: .NET Framework 4.7.3416.0

PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432:
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 8

Is64BitProcess: True
Is64BitOperatingSystem: True

    Func1Double,      Func1Float,     Func2Double,      Func2Float
             31,              31,             375,              32
             31,              15,             375,              32
             31,              31,             391,              31
             31,              16,             375,              31
             31,              16,             375,              31
             32,              31,             375,              15
             32,              31,             375,              16
             31,              31,             375,              16
             31,              31,             375,              16
             16,              31,             375,              32
Done


D:\files\dev\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble>BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x86-release.exe

OSDescription: Microsoft Windows 10.0.16299
OSArchitecture: X64
ProcessArchitecture: X86
FrameworkDescription: .NET Framework 4.7.3416.0

PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432: AMD64
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: x86
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 8

Is64BitProcess: False
Is64BitOperatingSystem: True

    Func1Double,      Func1Float,     Func2Double,      Func2Float
           1219,            1203,             375,             375
           1219,            1203,             375,             375
           1219,            1203,             375,             375
           1219,            1234,             375,             375
           1219,            1219,             375,             375
           1234,            1219,             375,             375
           1218,            1219,             375,             375
           1219,            1203,             375,             375
           1219,            1219,             375,             375
           1218,            1250,             375,             375
Done


D:\files\dev\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble>BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x64-debug.exe

OSDescription: Microsoft Windows 10.0.16299
OSArchitecture: X64
ProcessArchitecture: X64
FrameworkDescription: .NET Framework 4.7.3416.0

PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432:
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 8

Is64BitProcess: True
Is64BitOperatingSystem: True

    Func1Double,      Func1Float,     Func2Double,      Func2Float
           1453,            1547,             485,             453
           1437,            1531,             454,             453
           1407,            1500,             453,             453
           1422,            1515,             453,             469
           1406,            1500,             469,             453
           1391,            1500,             453,             469
           1406,            1500,             453,             469
           1422,            1500,             453,             469
           1390,            1500,             469,             453
           1406,            1516,             469,             469
Done


D:\files\dev\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble>BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x86-debug.exe

OSDescription: Microsoft Windows 10.0.16299
OSArchitecture: X64
ProcessArchitecture: X86
FrameworkDescription: .NET Framework 4.7.3416.0

PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432: AMD64
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: x86
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 8

Is64BitProcess: False
Is64BitOperatingSystem: True

    Func1Double,      Func1Float,     Func2Double,      Func2Float
           1719,            1672,             484,             469
           1719,            1687,             484,             454
           1718,            1688,             484,             469
           1703,            1688,             484,             453
           1734,            1750,             500,             485
           1750,            1750,             500,             469
           1765,            1735,             500,             468
           1766,            1687,             485,             469
           1703,            1687,             485,             468
           1766,            1719,             484,             500
Done
```

And the commands for generating the IL for closer inspection.

```
D:\files\dev\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble>ildasm BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x64-debug.exe /out=BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x64-debug.exe.il

D:\files\dev\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble>ildasm BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x64-release.exe /out=BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x64-release.exe.il

D:\files\dev\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble>ildasm BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x86-debug.exe /out=BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x86-debug.exe.il

D:\files\dev\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble\BenchmarkFloatVsDouble>ildasm BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x86-release.exe /out=BenchmarkFloatVsDouble-x86-release.exe.il
```

[image: IL Compare]

https://github.com/gregmulvihill/BenchmarkFloatVsDouble

Comment: Since you're not using any of the results at all, it's disappointing that your compiler doesn't inline and fully optimize away all your functions, leaving just an empty `i++` loop for all 4!  (Debug-mode benchmarking is basically useless, and not a meaningful predictor of release-mode performance.)  IMO you should edit your question to put the release-mode results first; those are the "real" numbers without artificially de-optimizing in a debug build.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the suggestion.  I agree that debug benchmarking is mostly useless.

Comment: Yup, that's better.  Comparing 64-bit release-mode vs. 32-bit release mode shows a bunch of surprising missed-optimizations for 32-bit mode.  The times all being nearly identical might indicate it was using legacy x87, where everything is promoted to 80-bit internally so `float` division and `double` division are both the same slow `fdiv`.  (The other simple FP operations (add, sub, mul), have performance independent of the data (not counting subnormals) on modern CPUs.)  Surprising there isn't more difference in the speed of the float vs. double Exp library function, unless it used x87, too.

Comment: (see https://agner.org/optimize/ for more details about asm performance). 
 Looking at the actual asm would probably be more enlightening; details of how the CIL compiles to native asm and/or optimizes away are clearly important.  e.g. for 64-bit, you're not actually testing anything except the strange missed-optimization of `Func2Double`; you'll probably just find empty loops, not SSE2 or AVX instructions doing FP math.